# Trying to switch between threads using condition_variables

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have two threads. Both get initialized, but the first thread runs first, while the second thread waits for the first thread (`call_once(flagEven1, [&](){cond2.wait(lock, [&](){return zeroEvenOddFlag == 1; }); });`). After a certain condition is met, the first thread wakes up the second thread and goes to sleep.

```
                zeroEvenOddFlag = 0;
                cond1.notify_all();
                cond2.wait(lock, [&](){return zeroEvenOddFlag == 1; });
```

This process alternates until the task is finished. Right now the threads just get locked up and I don't know what's happening. The threads together should process the input string and produce two strings of zeros and non-zero numbers. I corrected for spurious wakeups by adding an integer that is shared between the threads (`zeroEvenOddFlag`).

```
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

mutex mu;
condition_variable cond1;
condition_variable cond2;

once_flag flagZero;
once_flag flagEven;
once_flag flagEven1;
int zeroEvenOddFlag = 0;

string printerFunc(queue<char>& input, int zeroEvenOdd, once_flag& flag){
    string output = "";
    function<void(string&)> f;
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mu);
    call_once(flag, [&](){
        if (zeroEvenOdd == 1){
            f = [&](string& output){
                int i = input.front() - '0';
                if (i == 0){ 
                output += to_string(i); 
                input.pop();
                }
                else {
                    zeroEvenOddFlag = 1;
                    cond2.notify_all();
                    cond1.wait(lock, [&](){return zeroEvenOddFlag == 0; });
                }
            };
        }
        else if (zeroEvenOdd == 2){
            call_once(flagEven1, [&](){cond2.wait(lock, [&](){return zeroEvenOddFlag == 1; }); });
            f = [&](string& output){
                int i = input.front() - '0';
                if (i != 0){ 
                    output += to_string(i); 
                    input.pop();
                }
                else {
                    zeroEvenOddFlag = 0;
                    cond1.notify_all();
                    cond2.wait(lock, [&](){return zeroEvenOddFlag == 1; });
                }
            };
        }
    });
    while(input.size()!=0){
        f(output);
    }
    return output;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     string input = "0102030";
     queue<char> inputQueue;
     for(char c : input){
         inputQueue.push(c);
     }
     auto zeros = async(launch::async, printerFunc, ref(inputQueue), 1, ref(flagZero));
     auto evens = async(launch::async, printerFunc, ref(inputQueue), 2, ref(flagEven));
     string zerosString = zeros.get();
     string evensString = evens.get();
     cout << "these are the zeros " << zerosString << endl;
     cout << "these are the evens " << evensString << endl;

     this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(10));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You definitely need to get a good book on multi-threading using C++11... You seem to be misusing `std::call_once`; You also don't take into account spurious wake-ups of `std::condition_variable::wait`, among a host of other issues..

Comment: How am I misusing call_once? I want to set the function once, which is why I have call_once(flag, [&](). There are reasons why I want to set the function once, which is immaterial to the question at hand. The other call_once is to prevent the second thread from even starting until the first thread gives it the go-ahead.
As for condition_variable::wait, I only have one condition for the wake up of thread two, and that is thread one waking it up. How do I deal with spurious wake-ups condition_variable::wait when all that matters is that the threads alternate?

Comment: If `call_once`  is immaterial to the question at hand, then why you don't simplify your code?

Comment: The REASON that I'm using call_once is immaterial. I still need to use call_once.

Comment: @WhiZTiM, I tried adding a clause to guard against spurious wake-ups. I don't understand how I am using `call_once` improperly, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to always check for spurious wake-ups conditions. The use of `cond2.wait(lock, [&](){return zeroEvenOddFlag == 1; });` and the like help check. Also, you reach an issue at the end of your loop. Which ever thread finally owns the mutex has to release it when it consumes the last bit of the queue, so that the other threads can be freed up to finish. The final code should look like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

mutex mu;
condition_variable cond1;
condition_variable cond2;

once_flag flagZero;
once_flag flagEven;
once_flag flagEven1;
int zeroEvenOddFlag = 0;

string printerFunc(queue<char>& input, int zeroEvenOdd, once_flag& flag){
    string output = "";
    function<void(string&)> f;
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mu);
    call_once(flag, [&](){
        if (zeroEvenOdd == 1){
            f = [&](string& output){
                    int i = input.front() - '0';
                    if (i == 0){
                        output += to_string(i);
                        input.pop();
                        if (input.size() == 0){
                            zeroEvenOddFlag = 1;
                            cond2.notify_all();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        zeroEvenOddFlag = 1;
                        cond2.notify_all();
                        cond1.wait(lock, [&](){return zeroEvenOddFlag == 0; });
                    }
            };
        }
        else if (zeroEvenOdd == 2){
            call_once(flagEven1, [&](){cond2.wait(lock, [&](){return zeroEvenOddFlag == 1; }); });
            f = [&](string& output){
                    int i = input.front() - '0';
                    if (i != 0){
                        output += to_string(i);
                        input.pop();
                        if (input.size() == 0){
                            zeroEvenOddFlag = 0;
                            cond1.notify_all();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        zeroEvenOddFlag = 0;
                        cond1.notify_all();
                        cond2.wait(lock, [&](){return zeroEvenOddFlag == 1; });
                    }
            };
        }
    });
    while(input.size()!=0){
        f(output);
    }
    return output;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     string input = "0102030";
     queue<char> inputQueue;
     for(char c : input){
         inputQueue.push(c);
     }
     auto zeros = async(launch::async, printerFunc, ref(inputQueue), 1, ref(flagZero));
     auto evens = async(launch::async, printerFunc, ref(inputQueue), 2, ref(flagEven));
     string zerosString = zeros.get();
     string evensString = evens.get();
     cout << "these are the zeros " << zerosString << endl;
     cout << "these are the evens " << evensString << endl;

     this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(10));
    return 0;
}
```